# ROBOT Framework headless browser execution stuck / taking time

Tags: robotframework, headless-browser

While running the ROBOT Framework scripts (GUI tests) in Headless Chrome, execution taking long time.

For Wait until element visible, in debug file, POST command is returning 200 and stuck. Not moving to next step, nor failing the script.

I need to terminate the execution.

Any way to overcome this problem? Thanks.

Version details:
Python - 3.8.5, RF - 3.22, RF Selenium - 4.5, Selenium - 3.141

Comment: do you have to stick with selenium? if not give robotframework-browser a try (it's modern library based on Microsoft's playwright - https://github.com/microsoft/playwright - a.k.a. Selenium killer) --> check it out: https://github.com/MarketSquare/robotframework-browser

Comment: btw. I had no issues with headless execution with robotframework-browser so far

Answer (score 0):

Try to update Selenium library, latest version is 5.1.3.

```
pip install --upgrade robotframework-seleniumlibrary
```

Update your browser and browser driver then give a try.

Comment: I have RF-Selenium 5.1 only. Still facing same issue. When scripts are running from CMD (headless mode), I need to press ESC to move from that stuck point.